# How can I recover from a "Bitcoin not sent" error on Bitcoin wallet

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-wallet-app, error

I use the Bitcoin wallet by the Bitcoin Wallet Developers.
Wallet 9.03, Android 9, Huawei P10 Plus.
After trying to send bitcoin to my Coinbase account, the message "Bitcoin not sent" appears in my Bitcoin wallet, but the bitcoins are gone.

Neither have they arrived in my Coinbase wallet, so basically the bitcoins are just gone at this moment.

I have sent a "crash report" to bitcoin.wallet.developers@gmail.com, but have not received a response. It's about 1 week since I've tried this.

Comment: Do you have any more information, such as a txid or address (if you're willing to reveal those)? Note that this isn't a helpdesk, and there are likely no developers working on that particular wallet here, so it's unlikely we can actually help resolving the issue. It may be possible for people here to help figure out what happened, though.